# Is there a method that gets bulk tweets in sttwitter?

Tags: ios, twitter, sttwitter

Is there a method that exposes https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/lookup in STTwitter?

I want to lookup and get the statuses for all the tweetId's in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see [-[STTwitterAPI getStatusesLookupTweetIDs:includeEntities:trimUser:map:successBlock:errorBlock:]](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/2e84e72b8f5bb3d1e14c4693bfc3e7cb0f6a8aac/STTwitter/STTwitterAPI.h#L1921-L1926).